Computing average temperature inside an area in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API
So I used this code to visualize an average temperature in an area:
var gaul = ee.FeatureCollection(
  'FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2')
var kerala = gaul.filter(
  ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME', 'Uusimaa'))
Map.addLayer(kerala, {color: 'purple'}, 'Admin2 Boundaries')
Map.setCenter(24,60,8)

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GCOM-C/L3/LAND/LST/V1')
                .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01')
                // filter to daytime data only
                .filter(ee.Filter.eq('SATELLITE_DIRECTION', 'D'));
                //visualiation
var visualization = {
  bands: ['LST_AVE'],
  min: 250,
  max: 316,
  palette: [
    '040274','040281','0502a3','0502b8','0502ce','0502e6',
    '0602ff','235cb1','307ef3','269db1','30c8e2','32d3ef',
    '3be285','3ff38f','86e26f','3ae237','b5e22e','d6e21f',
    'fff705','ffd611','ffb613','ff8b13','ff6e08','ff500d',
    'ff0000','de0101','c21301','a71001','911003',
  ]
};

// Multiply with slope coefficient
var dataset = dataset.mean().multiply(0.02);

//clip the data to an area
var clipped = dataset.clip(kerala)


Map.addLayer(clipped, visualization)

Is there a way I could now calculate the average temperature inside this area?

You can check user guide, documentation or any tutorial to do this here is where to look https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_region#reduceregion

@Es_a I tried that but that dataset is old and when I tried with a newer one (Lansat 8 tier 2 TOA), I still got an error "image.reduceRegion is not a function."

To calculate average value within an area you can use reduceRegion() in your code. https://code.earthengine.google.com/0e230d24a086cfffe6088c54b382b402
I recommended looking at a tutorial to know how reducer works in earth engine, rather than using the same data in there.

Managed to solve. Here's code
link
